# How to use: Password regular expression for different validation

Tags: android, regex, validation

I need two regexp to validate password. First regexp for any word and at least 8 characters. Second for any word and at least 8 characters but no space.
I want two regexp because I need to show different error message if password is to short and different if password contains space.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do your basic research first. Thanks!

Comment: So the first word can contain spaces and the second can't? How are they seperated?

Comment: @maja I use "\w{8,}" for first and "((\S)(\w).{8,})" for second.

Comment: @maja I need to show different error message for password validation. First if password is to short and second if password have space.

Comment: @DawidHyży The first regex you are using matches the following: "And word with at least 8 characters." However, the second matches "One symbol that is no whitespace. Then one word character. Then any other character, at least 8 times"

Comment: @DawidHyży Then why don't you say this in your question? If you have to provide different error messages, you can't solve this with a single regex. You need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77085/discussion-between-dawid-hyzy-and-maja).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resulting from the descussion, you need one regular expression for each check to perform.

- At least 8 characters: `^.{8,}$`
- No whitespace character: `^\S*$`
- Both combined: `^\S{8,}$`

Explanation:

- `^` Start of the string
- `$` End of the string
- `.` Any character (inclusive whitespace)
- `\S` Any characters that is not whitespace
- `{8,}` previous expression 8 or more times
- `*` previous expression zero or more times

In order to develop, analyse and test regular expressions you can tools like this: https://regex101.com/